# docker container name sometimes already in use after stop

Tags: docker

I have a Jenkins job that replaces a docker container with the latest image overnight. Usually this works but occasionally this fails with the error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: Conflict. The container name "/demo-api" is already in use by container
```

The Jenkins job uses the following:

```
docker stop demo-api
./api_container.sh
```

`api_container.sh` does a `docker pull` and `docker run --name demo-api -t -d --rm`.

However when I `ssh` on in the morning after a failure and run `docker ps` the container is no longer running so looks like it does stop eventually, just not in time for the `docker run` command that tries to start it with the new image.

**Questions**
Does the [`docker stop`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stop/) command not block until it returns?
Should I handle this differently in my Jenkins job script?
I've seen there's also a [`docker wait`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/wait/) command. Should I be using that too in my script?

Comment: I don't know the root cause, but if it happens, then use `docker ps -a | grep demo-api` to detect if it's there before `docker run --name demo-api -t -d --rm.` seems is the only way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure you have a race condition here. Stop will return before the `--rm` takes effect. So it's a race between the `--rm` handled by the engine and the `api_container.sh` script.

I'd use an explicit `docker rm` to avoid the race. Note the `docker rm` may fail depending on where `--rm` is in its processing, and I'd handle that with a short sleep just to be sure it's done.

```
docker stop demo-api
docker rm demo-api || sleep 5
./api_container.sh
```

Or you can switch to a `docker rm -f` which will kill and delete the container in one step. Probably what you really want, and less error prone, but can leave volumes in a bad state if the app dies ungracefully.

```
docker rm -f demo-api
./api_container.sh
```

Comment: I think this output from my script following the addition of `docker rm demo-api` confirms that it's a race condition: `Error response from daemon: removal of container demo-api is already in progress`.

Answer (score 0):

`docker stop` will stop your container.

All the stopped container can be found in this command.

`docker ps --filter "status=exited`

The error you got says `The container name "/demo-api" is already in use by container`

It means there is already a container using `demo-api` name, which is true since stopping a docker container will not remove that container and that container name will exists.

All you have to do is

either

Run `docker run` command without specifying `--name` option which gives name to your container `demo-api`. So that each time your script pulls and run the container it will get a new random container name.

OR

If you want to keep your container name same `demo-api` then rather than stopping the container using `docker stop` Just remove the container all together `docker rm -f demo-api`

**UPDATE**

I just saw you updated your question.

Stopping a container which was ran using `--rm` option should remove that 
container all together.

The error you got seems to only exists when the name is already in-use by another container.

So far you can try to run your script in a while loop and check if that occurs during this run.

Here is the script I used (but didn't got any issue), try this on your particular machine where this issue occurs.

```
#!/bin/bash
i=20
while [ $i -gt 0 ]
do
docker stop demo-api
docker pull alpine
docker run --name demo-api -t -d --rm alpine sh
i=$((i - 1))
done
```

Comment: I've added some more detail to the question: I use `docker run` with `--rm` so the container is removed on exit. What I don't understand is why this only fails intermittently, most nights it works.